# Laravel Nova Searchable Select In Action

Tags: laravel-nova

I have a requirement to create an action to clone some assets to a new organization.  I want to give admin user provision to select the assets and then select an organization and run the action to transfer the assets. But we have a long list of assets and also organizations. So the whole hanged up cause it was trying to load all the org list for each asset. Is there any way to have searchable option in Nova action?

```
        $organizations = resolve('App\Repository\OrganizationRepository\OrganizationRepositoryInterface')->getAll()->pluck('company_name', 'id');

    return [
        Select::make('Organization', 'id')->rules('required', 'exists:organizations,id')->options($organizations)
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Nova ^3.0, the Select field comes with the `searchable` method, so you may use it like this:

```php
return [
    Select::make('Organization', 'id')
        ->searchable()
        ->rules('required', 'exists:organizations,id')
        ->options($organizations)
];
```

The Nova documentation has a example image: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#searchable-select-fields